# populate Multiple(4) spinner in activity from webservice based on each spinner selection

Tags: android, xml, web-services, android-spinner, dynamic-data

[image: This is the layout ,I am going have in a activity]

The data for populate spinner are completely from webservice(xml).
app doesn't maintain any local data for spinner data populating...

I need to get every spinner value based on selection of spinner value one by one by using webservice in dynamic way.
populate a country by webservice.
Based on country, populate city by webservice.
based on country and city, populate pincode by webservice.
based on country,city and pincode, populate bank_name by webservice and goes on.

How can i achieve this smoothly to get **greater user interface**.....

Comment: set click listener for every spinner and call appropriate webservice and put data in next spinner

Comment: @Divyesh  is it smoothly working in UI ?

Comment: yes, use proper way to set listener

Answer (score 0):

```
    If you are recieving array value of all spiiners in api then you also need the values which is select by default in that api.


    i.e
    {
    data:{
    city:[
    "X",
    "Y",
    "Z"
    ]
    },
    dataSelected:{
    city:"X"
    }
    }

//after parsing

spinnerCity.setadaper(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.layout_simple_spinner_dropdown_table, arrCity));

 String selectedStr = "X";
                        String cap = selectedStr.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + selectedStr.substring(1);
                        int spinnerPosition = arrCity.indexOf(cap);
                        spinnerCity.setSelection(spinnerPosition);
```

Comment: For parsing, is AsynTask works well? because it need to load data by parsing value from webservice in same activity,after each selection.

Comment: you should use Async Task for parsing once and further store the response and do the operation by stored response.

Comment: I didn't make this call at once. Actually i need to call webservice after selecting spinner value(i need to send the selected spinner value as parameter to the next webservice to fetch value from server.).

Comment: `spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) 
    {
       //call service here with params and get data for next spinner and fill that
  new abc().execute(spinner.getSelectedItem(position).toString());

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) 
    {
       
    }
});`